# iOS - app containing another app

Tags: iphone, ios, compiled

I would like to hand my application to another developer to assymilate in his iOS app.
The goal is to have, in his app, a shortcut that opens my app directly - not just a link to the appstore.
The problem is my app has to remain compiled, since I don't want to hand over my source-code.
Is this situation, of one compiled iOS app, encapsulated insind another iOS app, even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All code in an app bundle has to be staticly linked, so you would have to rewrite and compile your app as a linkable shared library.

Comment: Hey hotpaw2. tnx for you answer. Are you sure i can, using the method you noted, get a "nested" app that can be opened and replace the container app in the foreground?

Comment: Almog - After static linking, they will be the same app under the same icon.

Answer (score 5):

Your application can register a custom URL handler that will launch it whenever any application will follow that URL. It can be triggered from Safari but it can also be triggered from any other application.

[Here's](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) how you enable that feature in your app and handle incomming passed parameters etc.

Comment: Hey RaYell, thank you for your response. If i use a URL scheme then don't my app should already be downloaded and installed on the user's device? I'm interested in downloading just one app that will be able to open another one inside it. Can I achieve that using a URL scheme?

Comment: If your app is not installed on the device (or any other app that registers the same URL handler) then those calls are going to be ignored, but the app should work fine

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking to do really isn't possible.  Each app has it's own code structure and can't be embedded into another app (MainWindow.xib for example).  Each app is also signed by the developers private key, so that's an obstacle there. You can't just hand him a binary of your app.

What you could do is potentially take your .XIBs and view controllers and give them to him to implement.  This is easiest if there's no model that also has to be migrated over.  Then he can present your views to take advantage of the logic built into your view controllers.

It's not a trivial amount of work and of questionable value.  If you're not willing to share source code then none of the above is really going to work for you.

My advice would be as people above have mentioned and use a URL scheme in his app that refers to yours.  Yes, your app would need to be installed, but then there's a clear and unambiguous separation between his work and yours...